# Declare generic type in class type arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'd like to find a syntax that would make the following code work:

```
interface ValueAccessor<TValue> {
  returnValue(): TValue;
}

class Caller<TAccessor extends ValueAccessor> {
  public callAccessor<TValue>(accessor: TAccessor<TValue>): TValue {
    return accessor.returnValue();
  }
}
```

I'd like to keep the TAccessor type "generic" so that we can call the callAccessor method with any concrete implementation of ValueAccessor, whathever the type of the TValue.

Currently, I get the following compilation error on the Caller class definition:

```
Generic type 'ValueAccessor<TValue>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
```

Comment: There is no direct support in TypeScript for this; see the linked question and its answers, as well as [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), for more information.